# How use Select with spaced string in C#

Tags: c#

How to use this expression correctly with a space in the select query?

```
string expression = "'Loan' 'ID'='" + ViewState["name"];
DataRow[] sign = ((DataTable)ViewState["customer"]).Select(expression);
```

I get:

> Exception has Operand is missing after ID operator.

Comment: Are you trying to filter out everything in `ViewState["customer"]` and keep those that have a Loan ID of `ViewState["name"]`? Use `Where` then, and don't use a string as the query. Use a lambda

Comment: I am trying to get Loan ID from Viewstate["name"] and select that particular loan ID from Viewstate["customer"].

Comment: it is very unclear what you want. Can you show some sample inputs and outputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work and return datarow array.

```
DataRow[] sign = ((DataTable)ViewState["customer"]).Select("[Loan ID]='" + id_here +"'");
```